# Component inside Mat-tab: How to scroll inner component

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll, angular-material

I'm working on a small attendance project and have some table component within some mat-tab components. When there is overflow from the table, it scrolls the full component, I only want it to scroll the table on the inner component.

I have tried adding "overflow: auto" in these sections:

1. on the (app-attendance-table) selector
2. inside table component
3. ::ng-deep { .mat-tab-body { overflow: auto } }
4. on the (mat-tab-group) selector
5. wrapped (app-attendance-table) in an (ng-container) or (div) and adding overflow: auto

This is the outer component with tabs:

```
  <ng-container>
    <mat-form-field class="date">
      <input
        matInput
        [matDatepicker]="picker"
        placeholder="Select a Date"
        (dateInput)="addEvent($event)"
        [(ngModel)]="currentDate"
      />
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-tab-group>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let grade of result; let i = index">
      <mat-tab *ngIf="grade.length > 0" [label]="grades[i]">
        <app-attendance-table [dataSource]="grade"></app-attendance-table>
      </mat-tab>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-tab-group>
  <div *ngIf="this.result.length < 1 && !this.loading">
    No Records Found for The Date: {{ currentDate.toDateString() }}
  </div>
  <mat-spinner *ngIf="this.loading"> </mat-spinner>
</div>
```

This is the actual table component itself:

```
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">


    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Student Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let student"
        ><span
          [ngClass]="{
            absent: student.isAbsent() && !student.Reason,
            finished: student.isAbsent() && student.Reason && !student.editing
          }"
        >
          {{ student.Name }}
        </span>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="grade">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Student Grade </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell
        [ngClass]="{
          absent: student.isAbsent() && !student.Reason,
          finished: student.isAbsent() && student.Reason && !student.editing
        }"
        *matCellDef="let student"
      >
        {{ student.Grade }}
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell
        [ngClass]="{
          absent: student.isAbsent() && !student.Reason,
          finished: student.isAbsent() && student.Reason && !student.editing
        }"
        *matCellDef="let student"
      >
        {{ student.Status }}
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="reason">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Reason </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let student">
        <mat-form-field
          class="reasons"
          *ngIf="!student.isPresent()"
          appearance="outline"
        >
          <mat-select
            [(ngModel)]="student.Reason"
            [disabled]="!student.editing"
            placeholder="Select Reason"
            (selectionChange)="makeChange(student)"
          >
            <mat-option
              *ngFor="let reason of reasons; let i = index"
              [value]="reason"
              [disabled]="student.Reason === reason"
            >
              {{ reason }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="comments">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Comments </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let student">
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="!student.isPresent()">
          <input
            matInput
            [(ngModel)]="student.Comments"
            [disabled]="!student.editing"
            (input)="makeChange(student)"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let student">
        <button
          *ngIf="!student.isPresent() && !student.editing"
          mat-raised-button
          color="primary"
          (click)="startEditing(student)"
        >
          Edit
        </button>
        <button
          *ngIf="!student.isPresent() && student.editing"
          mat-raised-button
          color="warn"
          (click)="saveEdits(student)"
        >
          Finish
        </button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

[image: Picture of component]

Comment: Wrap your `<app-attendance-table [dataSource]="grade"></app-attendance-table>` in a`div`, fix it's height and set autoscroll. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the table is scrollable, wrap the table inside `div` with a fixed height and make its `overflow: auto`.

You can also check below links that has both page as well as table as scrollable.

1. https://angular-qfqpwr.stackblitz.io (Working Stackblitz)
2. https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples (Table with sticky header)

Answer (score 0):

To extend on @Pankaj Prakash's answer, you should set the overflow property on your outer container to  `overflow: hidden`.

Then wrap a  `div` around the mat cells and set the  property to `overflow: scroll`. If you only want a vertical scroll you could also set the following property instead:  `overflow-y: scroll`